# Chaos and Order: a visual puzzle in stained glass

Tags: mathematics, geometry, visual, steganography, enigmatic-puzzle

I created a visual puzzle, which my wife then implemented as part of a stained-glass window. I've no idea if it is (a) obvious, (b) stupid or hopefully (c) extremely clever, and hence would love to hear your opinion.

Here's a photo. What does it represent?

[image: Order and Chaos]

Comment: i guess size of each block represent a number and they are from $1$ to $9$. e.g. upper-left block is $3*1$ so it's number should be $3$.

Comment: also the red circle may illustrate something like starting point.

Comment: "as part of a stained-glass window"... does the "part" that is your puzzle exactly correspond to the picture?

Comment: @EnvisionAndDevelop: yes, the photo is just a part of the whole window. The whole window is much larger, with this photo being roughly the top-right quarter. The other three-quarters of the window is not relevant to the puzzle.

Comment: Hey, come up with some more of these!

Comment: I thought it was a green elephant with blue clothes and a yellow crown, LOL.

Comment: Why there is  red dot?

Comment: @AlwaysConfused - it is a decimal point

Comment: @MattClarke Thank you for inspiring [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/101387/disarray-and-organization-a-virtual-mosaic-puzzle).

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Solved it! Spoilers ahead:

> Superposition of [image: blue] and [image: yellow]

---

> It's a combination of two numbers represented in yellow and blue panes, with
>  green panes indicating where they overlap.
>  
>  The blue panes give the digits of $\pi$ (3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5)
>  
>  and the yellow panes are the digits of the first [Feigenbaum constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feigenbaum_constants) (4, 6, 6, 9, 2, 0, 1, 6, 1).

P.S. I think this window is brilliant :-)

Comment: indeed. interesting puzzle! +1 to both

Comment: do you know how do these two numbers connected? I never heard about Feigenbaum constant before and IMHO it is very strange to make pattern-puzzle that is based on it.

Comment: and what does red point mean?

Comment: @klm123 The two numbers relate to the title of this question, and as Rafe suggested, the red dot marks the starting point (or perhaps a *decimal* point).

Comment: Thanks for the compliment @squeamishossifrage. I only wish it had taken you a bit longer to decipher -- I thought it was a harder puzzle than that! And yes, I think of the red dot as a decimal point.

Comment: Bah! Tau is better!

Comment: @bjb568 #TheTauPeople

Comment: Holy crap this is clever (and pretty).