# What does this picture represent?

Tags: mathematics, rebus

What does this picture represent in math?

> [image: What does this picture represent in math?]

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! I added a **Mathematics** tag to your puzzle and formatted it slightly (I added 2 spaces to the end of your question to put the picture on its own line).

Comment: (Not exact, but basically the same concept)

Comment: Yes, after trying to solve it, I realized it is not the same. There is something else to this puzzle. Rectracted Close Vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**

Rows

> NL628's answer of the rows begin equal to e as in 2.718281828.

Columns

> The columns are equal to pi as in 3.14592653 which is the number of blue and orange squares in the column.

Comment: Ahhh Good Job lol :D

Answer (score 1):

Partial Solve:

> The rows create the number $e = 2.718281828$ (Taken from [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/2258/43256))

Still can't find out how columns work.