# Disarray and Organization: a virtual mosaic puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, geometry, steganography

I created this mosaic, which references a country I like to visit in my spare time.
What country is that?

[image]

Comment: Another very nice puzzle! Although I think people are a little stuck on your last one, might want to comment on their answers :)

Comment: Thank you for your interest @BeastlyGerbil! I'd like to give it a few more days though ;)

Comment: They've been too very nice (and also very aesthetically pleasing) first puzzles! Oh and I wasn't suggesting a hint, bit simply something like a comment saying 'well done' or 'all correct so far' to let them know they're on the right track :) Definitely don't give any hints too quickly!

Comment: Thank you very much for all the compliments! Ah, now I see. Yes I will provide some comments! Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Huh, my avatar is using a very similarly looking code, although not related

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If we

> take all the red, then green, then blue triangles (treating white as "none" rather than "all"), we get the following images:
>  [image] [image] [image]
>  Each of these can be interpreted as ASCII in a different direction. For instance, the leftmost column in the red is `01010000`, making a `P`.
>  [image]
>  The red, going downwards, spells `Power`. The green, going up-leftwards, reads `Courage`. And the blue, going  up-rightwards, reads `Wisdom`. These are the three components of the Triforce from the Legend of Zelda series.

So the country you're visiting in your spare time is

> Hyrule, the realm from the Legend of Zelda!

Comment: Very quick, well done! Thanks for solving my puzzle!

Comment: I'm not sure I see the ascii, even with your description. How do you read the words in the images?

Comment: @AnthonyIngram-Westover Added an example - hopefully it's clearer now!

Comment: @Deusovi Ahh, that does make a lot of sense. Very well done!